# fireEvent.mouseOver document.createRange is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I am unable to use `fireClick.mouseOver(tab)` using for testing tooltip on tab hover.

Below is the code snippet.

```
  it('should handle change on hover of tab', () => {

    const {getByTestId, getByRole} = renderComponent('Draft');
    const tab0 = getByTestId('tab-0');
    fireEvent.mouseOver(tab0);

    expect(getByRole('tooltip')).not.toBeNull();
  }
```

I am getting exception as "`document.createRange is not a function`"

However `fireEvent.click(tab)` is working good.

Comment: is it the same https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15726 ?

Answer (score 0):

One reason you might be getting the error is because `role="tooltip"` is nowhere to be found in the DOM meaning either the HTML node does not exist or the property `role` is absent.

If it exists, then update jest to 26+
for instance:  `"jest": "^26.4.2"` which should clear the issue